# Build API without the WolframCloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, webmathematica, mathematica-online, apifunction

I'd like to have my code and api deployed, *but not to the Wolfram Cloud*. I have a an `APIFunction`, and I'd like to `CloudDeploy` it to a specific url backed by my own instance.

**Notes:**

- I don't see anything in the docs on this so I'm thinking it might not be possible.
- I'm running on my own ec2 box with mathematica 10.4 installed.

Comment: A private Wolfram Cloud would be one way to do this. The currently advertised [private cloud](https://billing.wolfram.com/pricing/wpc) could be on your server, but is priced to include custom installation, maintenance, and support by Wolfram Research.

Comment: I'd like this too, but a private cloud is the only way to do it and I'm pretty sure the price is stratospheric.

Comment: Are you running a server-side platform (PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, Node.js, Go etc.) on your ec2 box?

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock I have a flask app

Answer (score 7):

Currently `APIFunction` / `CloudDeploy` works only with the Public Cloud or an Enterprise Private Cloud.

So either you need an EPC on your side or you can use WebMathematica or Mathematica (WebMMA license required anyway). Though WebMMA does not support `APIFunctions` anyway so you'd have to adapt it to create JSP based api interface.

Let's hope someone in WRI sees the potential and an upgrade for WebMMA is on the way.

Comment: Nominally you could imagine running it through the little `WebServer` stuff in the ``"HTTPHandling`"`` context and then using python or something as a little interface server layer...but that basically buys you nothing. *Maybe* one day we'll hack that stuff to allow us to expose it more broadly but I'm not sure and I certainly don't care enough to figure this out without some compelling use case.

Comment: @b3m2a1 "..and then using python or something as a little interface server layer"  sounds like what WRI did with WolframWebEngine, see answer below.

Comment: I really think that `Wolfram Research` is missing the boat on this. Currently, the biggest problem with building applications in `Wolfram Language`--something that is often *far* easier to do than in other languages--is the final step of delivering the solution to a client who does not have Wolfram infrastructure. By creating a reasonably-priced option, `Wolfram Research` would explode its user base, since it has so much else going for it.

Answer (score 4):

Now there's [WolframWebEngine](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframWebEngineForPython) which allows one to create a sort of personal wolfram cloud.